# C++ template for specific type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

So I have this little template class:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>{} || std::is_same<T, std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>>{}, int>::type = 0>
class Accumulator
{
  public:
    void Sample(const T value) {
        value_ = Convert(value);
    }
  private:
    float value_;
}
```

It needs to work for all arithmetic types and `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>` type. There is some math inside to be done, so all the passed values to `Sample()` method will have to be converted to `float`.

What is a good elegant way to write this `Convert()` function? I've tried writing an entire version of `Accumulator` for `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>` type, but it looked like a code duplication. Making specific `Convert(std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano> value)` didn't work with a different version `Convert(T value)`.

C++14 on gcc 9.3.0.

Comment: I don't see what would be the problem with `Convert`

Comment: It's a bit pointless to take non-reference arguments as `const`. You are already guaranteeing the caller that you won't be mutating what they pass in because you are taking the argument by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>{} || std::is_same<T, std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>>{}, int>::type = 0>
class Accumulator
{
  public:
    void Sample(const T value) {
        value_ = Convert(value);
    }
  private:
    float value_;
};
template <class U>
float Convert(U value) {
   // default overload
}
inline float Convert(std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano> value) {
    // specialization for duration
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the specialization, you can just overload the function with a non-template version (as long as the caller doesn't explicitly specify template arguments).